# Return records based on min data in source and target if conditions satisfied in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi I have data in sql server 
Table : emp

```
Empid  | deptid  | doj          |  loc | Status|guid
1      |  10     | 2013-09-25   | hyd  |  5    |10
1      |  10     | 2014-03-25   | che  |  5    |11
1      |  10     | 2014-04-09   | pune |  5    |12
1      |  10     | 2015-01-22   | pune |  5    |13
2      |  20     | 2015-12-13   | beng |  5    |14
2      |  20     | 2014-12-17   | chen |  5    |15
2      |  20     | 2010-10-15   | beng |  4    |16
```

Table : empref

```
empid   | deptid  | startdate   | status |guid
1       |  10     | 2013-10-02  |   2    |1
1       |  10     | 2014-04-09  |   2    |2
1       |  10     | 2015-12-09  |   1    |3
1       |  10     | 2015-01-30  |   2    |4
2       |  20     | 2015-12-14  |   2    |2
2       |  20     | 2015-12-15  |   2    |3
```

Both tables have common columns Empid + deptid 
We need to consider emp table status=5 related records compare with empref table status=2 
related records and emp table doj <= startdate --empref table and days difference between less than or equal to 30 days 
If we find multiple records fall within 30 days  in empref table startdate then we need to consider  min(startdate) corresponding records
and that records need to be considered as update.  Remain status values 4 or 1 no need in the return result set at this time.

If emp table status=5 related records compare with empref table status=2
related records and emp table doj <= startdate --empref table and daysdiffernce between less than or equal 30 days 
If we find multiple records fall with in 30days  in emp table doj then we need to consider  min(doj) corresponding records
and that record needs to be considered as update in the filter column and guid information from empref table.
Remaining records considered as insert records in the filter column and guid information from emptable.

if emp table doj <=startdate--empref table condition not satisfied or
daysdiffernce not between less than or equal 30 days then that records we need to consider insert in the filter column
based on above tables I want output like below

```
Empid  |   Deptid   |  loc   | Status  |   Filter    |  Doj       |guid
  1    |    10      |   hyd  |  5      |   Update    |  2013-09-25|1
  1    |    10      |   che  |  5      |   insert    |  2014-03-25|11  ------min(startdate) corresponding record
  1    |    10      |   pune |  5      |   update    |  2014-04-09|2 --------mul
  1    |    10      |   Pune |  5      |   update    |  2015-01-22|4 
  2    |    20      |   beng |  5      |   update    |  2015-12-13|2   --------------min(doj) record
  2    |    20      |   chen |  5      |   insert    |  2014-12-17|15 
  2    |    20      |   beng |  4      |   insert    |  2010-10-15|16 -----this record not fall the above conditions
```

I tried like below

```
select s1.*
,'Update' as Filter from emp e join empref er
on e.empid=er.empid and 
e.deptid=t.deptid
and e.status='5' 
and er.status='2' and
e.doj<=er.startdate and datediff(dd,er.startdate,e.doj)*-1<=30 
group by er.startdate,
e.empid,e.deptid.e.doj,e.loc
having e.startdate= min(er.startdate)
```

In the above query not given expected result. Please help me write this query to achieve this task in sql server.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the query you supplied is very close.  Here is what I quickly put together.  I haven't tested it against a lot of the possible options.

```
select e.Empid, er.deptid, e.loc, e.[status], 
case when DATEDIFF(DAY, e.doj, er.startdate) <= 0 THEN 'INSERT'
     ELSE 'UPDATE' END [DaysOffset],  
e.doj
FROM @emp e inner join @empref ER 
        on  e.Empid = er.empid and 
            e.deptid = er.deptid 
where e.[status] = 5 and er.[status] = 2
    and e.doj <= er.startdate and
        DATEDIFF(DAY, e.doj, er.startdate) <= 30
```

The CASE statement is where it determines when the record is flagged for INSERT or UPDATE.  With the datediff in the WHERE clause, it will only return records that are 30 days or less.

Comment: Hi given query very close to my expected result.I added guid column in emp and empref table for identification purpose update/insert. if update record means need to get guid from emprefs table insert record means need to get guid from emp table.here we need to check min(startdate) as well as min(doj).reason is both table side few records have foll multiples then we need to consider min dates.please tell me how to write query to achieve this task in sql server .